# How to get Enum Key list

Tags: c#, enums

Consider I have an `enum` type :

```
public enum PartyRoleTypeEnum
{
    Stdudent =20,
    Teacher =21,
    Manager =22
}
```

I'm trying to get `PartyRoleTypeEnum` keys by

```
list<int> result = Enum.GetValues(typeOf(PartyRoleTypeEnum)).CastTo<int>();
```

And I'm expecting `result` whould be  `List<int>{20,21,22}`

But it returns an empty list.

Comment: It should work that way. But your code would not even compile, so maybe you can post your *real* code, so we can see what went wrong.

Comment: You are right , I rewrite the code

Comment: This worked for me, which is about your exact code:`List<int> result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PartyRoleTypeEnum)).Cast<int>().ToList();`

Comment: @zaistsman  , It return nothing , I test it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
List<int> result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PartyRoleTypeEnum)).
                   .OfType<PartyRoleTypeEnum>().Select(x=> (int)x)
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried modifying your code and it works (after making it compile): http://csharppad.com/gist/2a87fe395ac2b66fa1d8

```
public enum PartyRoleTypeEnum
{
    Stdudent =20,
    Teacher =21,
    Manager =22
}

//--------

List<int> result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PartyRoleTypeEnum)).Cast<int>().ToList();

//--------

Console.WriteLine(result.Count); //Prints 3

//--------
//Prints 20,21,22
foreach(var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}


//--------
```

Comment: I'm afraid , But in my computer still it return nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
Array myArray = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PartyRoleTypeEnum));

foreach (var item in myArray)
    myList.Add((int)item);
```

Comment: That worked , Could you explain why my code doesn't ?

Comment: Sorry actually I don't know CastTo fucnction

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
List<int> result = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PartyRoleTypeEnum))
                       .Cast<int>()
                       .ToList();
```

The `Enum`'s method `GetValues` has the following signature:

```
public static Array GetValues(Type enumType)
```

It is clear from that this mehtod returns an `Array` object,  that contains the values of the constants in enumType, for further documentantio please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So that you want is to convert this array to a list, in order to assign it to the `result`. This can be done using the `IEnumerable's` `Cast` method and then calling in it the `IEnumerable's` `ToList` method. Note that there isn't any method called `CastTo`.

**Update**

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eL8LP1)

Comment: @Chgristos , I'm afraid I tried your way , But still the return type is an empty list

Comment: @Mostafa Have you tried the above and it didn't work? I could post a .netfiddle to see it.

Comment: Yes I assure you I test it , Maybe netfiddle not acting like a real compiler

Comment: I'm getting no error , Just the result is empty , I tried "Avi Turner" and "Mojtaba" code and those worked , Thank you